# React testing use mockstore with custom store to test it

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I would like to test components that are using redux store in my project. Here is the function that I use fo getting some store elements:

```
const variable = store.getState().serverConfiguration.testValue;
```

When I am testing this component I use `mockStore` to do that so my store is empty right? That is why I get error saying that `TypeError: Cannot read property 'testValue' of undefined`

Is there a way to pass my custom store to `mockStore` so that it will be possible to test it correctly?
I tried to do that like this but it doesn't work:

```
const store = configureMockStore()({
    serverConfiguration: {
       testValue: "Admin"
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import configureStore from "redux-mock-store"

const mockStore = configureStore([]);

const store = mockStore({
    serverConfiguration: {
        testValue: "Admin"
    }
})
```